# Monitoring User Activity in Django

Tags: python, django

I am creating a book app where users can sign up and start reading.

This is the model.py for the book:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

from django.conf import settings


class Chapter(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    date_completed = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("course:subchapter_list", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})


class SubChapter(models.Model):
    chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class SubSection(models.Model):
    sub_chapter = models.ForeignKey(SubChapter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    text = models.TextField(null=True, blank=False)

    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("course:detail",
                       kwargs={"slug": self.sub_chapter.slug,
                               "slug2": self.slug,
                               "pk": self.sub_chapter.chapter.pk,
                               }
                       )
```

How can I monitor each user's progress such that when a subsection/subchapter/chapter is viewed/read, that model instance's completed attribute is set to True just for that user? My current implementation sets completed to True for everyone.

I would appreciate code snippets demonstrating how you might implement it.

Comment: You may want to do this in your views, since this is done upon a get request by a specific user for one of your model instances.

Comment: You may want to consider making a base class, since I suspect there is a lot in common between your three classes, including the logic you're asking about.

Comment: You may also want to read through the [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) section of Django, but that may not be useful; it could also obfuscate some of the logic. First see if you can handle this in the get request for that particular view.

Comment: Maybe you can create a middleware, write some code to detect if a user is enter/exit a subsection/subchapter/chapter  and update model.

Comment: I have tried both approaches (views/middleware) with plenty of frustration. I would appreciate snippets of you might have handled such challenges. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to monitor the reading progress for every user, you can't have the completed fields on the `Chapter`, `SubChapter` and `SubSection` models, you need a new one related to the user. I would do something like this:

```
class ReadingProgress(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    completed_chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapter)
    completed_subchapter = models.ForeignKey(SubChapter)
    completed_subsection = models.ForeignKey(SubSection)
```

If you have different books, you should add foreign keys to the book model as well.

Then in the views that fetch the chapters, sections and so on, you can get the `ReadingProgress` object for the specific user (and book?) and set the corresponding values.

Comment: This is valid, but in my instance taxing for the programmer as it has to be completed in every single view, upon every tracked activity. I have a similar need as the OP, but it is quite a bit larger, I already have about a hundred views and we are still in the initial phases of development. I can store user activity by saving user info manually in each view, but that would still kind of suck to do. Is there not a Django way to track user navigation throughout the views of your project where I don't have to manually enter in required data pertaining to user activity?